# Flutter: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..3: 4 using IndexedListView.builder

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

I'm working on chat same as like whatsapp. I'm trying to do this feature, when user wants to reply on specific message and when on tap on the replied message it should jump up to that specific message. So to do this I'm using [indexed_list_view](https://pub.dev/packages/indexed_list_view) package.

**The problem is that it shows this error**

```
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..3: 4
```

but when i used `ListView builder` this error not occur.

**here is my code:**

```
class ChatRoom extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChatRoom({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ChatRoom> createState() => _ChatRoomState();
}

class _ChatRoomState extends State<ChatRoom> {
  List<ChatRoomModel> chatRoom = [
    ChatRoomModel(
        replyMsgIndex: 0,
        msg: "Hello",
        time: "09:00 PM",
        replyCount: 0,
        replyMsg: "",
        userId: 1),
    ChatRoomModel(
        replyMsgIndex: 0,
        msg: "Helloo",
        time: "12:00 PM",
        replyCount: 0,
        replyMsg: "",
        userId: 1),
    ChatRoomModel(
        replyMsgIndex: 0,
        msg: "Hellooo",
        time: "09:05 PM",
        replyCount: 0,
        replyMsg: "",
        userId: 1),
    ChatRoomModel(
        replyMsgIndex: 0,
        msg: "Helloooo",
        time: "10:00 PM",
        replyCount: 0,
        replyMsg: "",
        userId: 1),
  ];

 bool leftSelected = false;
  bool rightSelected = false;
  String replymsg = "";
  int? getMsgIndex;
  int? jumpIndex;
  int? changeColorIndex;
  TextEditingController newReply = TextEditingController();
IndexedScrollController controller = IndexedScrollController(initialIndex: 0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(60.0),
        child: CustomApp(
          name: name,
          imagePath: imagePath,
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(children: [
//here i am using the package
        Expanded(
          child: IndexedListView.builder(
              maxItemCount: chatRoom.length,  //i passed the lenght of list too
              controller: controller,
              itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
               

                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: jumpIndex == index
                            ? Colors.blue
                            : Colors.transparent,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
                    child: SwipeTo(
                      onRightSwipe: (() {
                        setState(() {
                          rightSelected = false;
                          leftSelected = true;
                          replymsg = chatRoom[index].msg;
                          getMsgIndex = index;
                          jumpIndex = index;
                          print("getMsgIndex  $getMsgIndex");
                        });
                      }),
                      child: Column(
//error points here                       
 crossAxisAlignment: chatRoom[index].userId == 1
                            ? CrossAxisAlignment.start
                            : CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: [
                         
                          chatRoom[index].replyCount == 1
                              ? InkWell(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    controller.jumpToIndex(jumpIndex!);
                                  },
                                  child: Container(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Colors.grey.shade100,
                                      border: const Border(
                                        left: BorderSide(
                                            color: Colors.purple, width: 3),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    child: Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                      children: [
                                        Text(name,style: const TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.purple,
                                                fontSize: 15,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                                        const SizedBox(height: 3),
                                        Text(chatRoom[index].replyMsg,
                                            style: const TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.black54,
                                              fontSize: 12,
                                            )),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )
                              : Text(
                                  chatRoom[index].replyCount > 0 &&
                                          chatRoom[index].replyMsg != ""
                                      ? chatRoom[index].replyMsg
                                      : "",
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 10.0,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                          Text(chatRoom[index].msg,
                              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0)),
                          Text(
                            "       " + chatRoom[index].time,
                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              })),
        ),
        Column(
          children: [
            leftSelected
                ? _replyWidget(replymsg)
                : AnimatedContainer(
                    duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
                  ),
            BottomTextField(
                newReply: newReply,
                sendMessageFunc: () {
//I'm adding new messages to list
                  setState(() {
                    leftSelected == true
                        ? chatRoom.add(
                            ChatRoomModel(
                                replyMsgIndex: jumpIndex,
                                userId: 2,
                                msg: newReply.text,
                                time: "09:00 PM",
                                replyCount: 1,
                                replyMsg: replymsg),
                          )
                        : chatRoom.add(ChatRoomModel(
                            replyMsgIndex: jumpIndex,
                            userId: 2,
                            time: "09:00 PM",
                            msg: newReply.text,
                            replyCount: 0,
                            replyMsg: ""));
                    leftSelected = false;
                    newReply.clear();
                    replymsg = "";
                  });
                })
          ],
        )
      ]),
    ));
  }
}
```

my screen looks like this when user redirect to this screen

[image]

Please help how to fix this error.

Comment: in which line this error happened?

Comment: @eamirho3ein check my code i update it where error points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `IndexedListView` from the [indexed_list_view](https://pub.dev/packages/indexed_list_view) package. The documentation on the first page looks like this:

> Limitation: The list is always infinite both to positive and negative indexes. In other words, it can be scrolled indefinitely both to the top and to the bottom.

This means that you can't specify the exact amount of items because `IndexedListView` works with **Infinity** lists

You have to manually check `index` and if it is in range of your collection then return the widget that represents the item or `null` to identify that you don't have anything to return

In short, your `itemBuilder` should look:

```
.. your code from above...
//error points here
child: index < 0 || index > chatRoom.length - 1 
    ? null
    : Column(crossAxisAlignment: chatRoom[index].userId == 1,
    ...
```

Also, do not forget that list will scroll in any way even if you don't have items to show because:

> You can define index bounds by giving it a minItemCount and maxItemCount, but this will not prevent the list from scrolling indefinitely. When showing items out of the index bounds, or when your itemBuilder returns null, it will ask the emptyItemBuilder to create an "empty" item to be displayed instead. As default, this will return empty containers.

Comment: but is there any way to stop the list scrollable when there are is no items?

Comment: I stop the scroll of IndexedListView.builder by doing this ```physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),``` and adding the ```SingleChildScrollView``` as it parent widget, but it is not working, any other way to do this?

Comment: Try to restrict it with minItemCount and maxItemCount